# Echoing functions, but not enough quotes available

Tags: php, html-table, echo

I am trying to echo out a signup form but am receiving the error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

I believe it is due to using to many `'` when call a function with variables but I am not sure how to fix it. I tried using `` ` `` but getting an error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Here is the form.

```
onblur='checkField('username', '1')'
```

is where I believe the error is happening

```
echo "<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input id='username' type='text' size='25'maxlength='25' onblur='checkField('username', '1')' /><div id=usernameHelp></div></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input id='password' type='password' size='25' maxlength='25' onblur='checkField('password', '2')'/><div id=passwordHelp></div></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Email: </td><td><input id='email' type='text' size='50' maxlength='50' onblur='checkField('email', '3')'/><div id=emailHelp></div></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input id='firstName' type='text' size='25' maxlength='25' onblur='checkField('name', '4')'/><div id=nameHelp></div></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Address:</td><td><input id='address' type='text' size='50' maxlength='50' onblur='checkField('address', '5')'/><div id=addressHelp></div></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input id='phone' type='text' size='10' maxlength='10' onblur='checkField('phone', '6')'/><div id=phoneHelp></div></td><input id='formAttempted' type='hidden' value='true' /></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><br /><br /></td><td><input onclick='signuper()' type='submit' value='Signup!' /><br />";

echo "</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Escape your quotes with backslash (` \ `)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd separate the HTML and PHP. This is a lot more cleaner and it'll be easier for you to change and maintain the code if it's separated.

```
<?php

//code

?>

<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input id='username' type='text' size='25'maxlength='25' onblur='checkField('username', '1')' /><div id=usernameHelp></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input id='password' type='password' size='25' maxlength='25' onblur='checkField('password', '2')'/><div id=passwordHelp></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email: </td><td><input id='email' type='text' size='50' maxlength='50' onblur='checkField('email', '3')'/><div id=emailHelp></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input id='firstName' type='text' size='25' maxlength='25' onblur='checkField('name', '4')'/><div id=nameHelp></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address:</td><td><input id='address' type='text' size='50' maxlength='50' onblur='checkField('address', '5')'/><div id=addressHelp></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input id='phone' type='text' size='10' maxlength='10' onblur='checkField('phone', '6')'/><div id=phoneHelp></div></td><input id='formAttempted' type='hidden' value='true' /></tr>
<tr><td><br /><br /></td><td><input onclick='signuper()' type='submit' value='Signup!' /><br />

</td></tr></table>
```

If you want to insert a variable in your HTML, you can use the following syntax:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>Some text: <?php echo $text; ?> </p>
</div>
```

If you want to do this inside if statements, you can use the following syntax:

```
<? if(some_condition){ ?>
     <!-- your HTML here -->
<? } ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This part of code is inside an if statement, which there is an else statement for checking if they are logged in. How would I go around this if i separate it?

Comment: Oh my lord! It worked! Thank you so much! This was really getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes within quotes. Mix them up or escape them.

```
onblur="checkField('username', '1')"
onblur='checkField("username", '1')'
```

Also, no need to wrap the integer in quotes.

Comment: Wouldnt that cause problems with the "" used for the echo?

Comment: If you're encho'ing it, then yes, in which case you should escape the quotes with a backslash. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

change this to

```
echo "<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input id='username' type='text' size='25'maxlength='25' onblur='checkField('username', '1')' /><div id=usernameHelp></div></td></tr>";
```

to

```
echo "<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input id='username' type='text' size='25'maxlength='25' onblur='checkField(\'username\', \'1\')' /><div id=usernameHelp></div></td></tr>";
```

for all checkField functions

Comment: Tried this and got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: escape for all checkField() functions